# Tест Api - PhpUnit. Kак задать headers и body?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты

```
$response = $this->client->post('/eng/api/set/rating/', [
        'headers' => ['token_id' => $token_id
                 ]
            ], ['body' => ['rating' => 7]
                ]);

$data = $response->json();
        $json = json_encode($data, 1);
        $jsonToArray = json_decode($json, 1);

/******************************************************/
{"Response":"Post Json Payload empty"}
```

Comment: а какой фреймворк тестится в данном случае?

Comment: PhpUnit Framework

Comment: Я спросил ЧТО Вы тестите, а не ЧЕМ. PhpUnit - это то, ЧЕМ тестите.